# Validation Backbone not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm getting the validation log "IS THIS EVEN WORKING" and if I put a log in the if statement, I get that as well. It just doesn't seem to be firing the the this.on('invalid') event. Any reason?

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: '',
        completed: false
    },
    validate: function(attrs){
        console.log("IS THIS EVEN WORKING");
        if(attrs.title == '' || !attrs.title){
            return "ya gone done messed it up";
        }
    },
    initialize: function(){
      console.log('todo model created'),
      /*this.on('change:title', function(){
          console.log(this.get('title') + 'values have changed');
      });*/
      this.on("invalid", function(model, error){
          console.log(error);
      })
    }
});


var todo2 = new Todo({
    completed:true
});

todo2.set('completed', false, {validate:true});

console.log(todo2.get('completed'));
```

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors in your initialize method, it should be semicolon instead of a comma and after your `this.on` your missing a semicolon. http://jsbin.com/dutijivono/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I should have seen the comma/semicolon thing (oops) but that fix ( those fixes ) doesn't get me my expected log which is the return from validate.

Comment: Did you look at the jsbin I linked to? It seems to work over there.

Comment: Yes. I've actually copied line by line your code over to my page. Is it possibly something to do with a localhost environment? I'm running it through MAMP and codekit. I get every log BUT the "ya gone done messed it up".

Comment: ......Tutorial had older version of backbone where I guess validation return was not invalid. 0.9.2 in the code. Needed replacement. Thank you. How  can I choose your answer as the answer and be done with this?

Comment: I'll write up an answer based on the comments and you can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In earlier versions of backbone (before 0.9.9) returning something from the validation method triggered an [`error`](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/0.9.2/index.html#Model-validate) event instead of `invalid`. Aside from that you have a couple of syntax errors, but that shouldn't stop it from working in most browsers.

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dutijivono/edit?html,js,console,output)